# no member named 'print' in 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'

Tags: smart-contract, string

if I declare a string and attempt to print it like this:

```
std::string s;
eosio::print(s);
```

the EOS compiler pukes:

> In file included from t.cpp:1: In file included from ./t.hpp:4: In
>   file included from
>   /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.4.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/eosiolib/asset.hpp:3:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/eosio.cdt/1.4.1/opt/eosio.cdt/bin/../include/eosiolib/print.hpp:237:9:
>   error: 
>         no member named 'print' in 'std::__1::basic_string'
>         t.print();
>         ~ ^ t.cpp:126:3: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>         'eosio::print &>' requested here
>                   print(ret);
>                   ^ 1 error generated.

but if I convert it:

```
eosio::print(std::string(s));
```

it works fine.  why is this necessary? `s` is already a string so why do I need this?

Answer (score 1):

As the compiler indicates

> .../include/eosiolib/print.hpp:237:9: error: no member named 'print' in 'std::__1::basic_string' t.print(); ...

after check the the source code of [print.hpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/cc840a4abcd6e0c56cc18edb3965961ce81c656f/libraries/eosiolib/print.hpp#L28)

```
inline void print( const std::string& s) {
  prints_l( s.c_str(), s.size() );
}

inline void print( std::string&& s) {
  prints_l( s.c_str(), s.size() );
}

...

template<typename T>
inline void print( T&& t ) {
   t.print();
}
```

then you will see that when you use

```
std::string s;
eosio::print(s);
```

it matches the **print( T&& t)** method best, so that will call the **string.print** which is not exist.

whereas use the

```
eosio::print(std::string(s));   // or eosio::print(std::move(s));
```

it matches the **print( std::string&& s)**

Comment: thank you for the explanation.  I may need some clarification... `std::string &&s` reads to me like `s` is the address of the address of a `std::string` -- is that correct or does it mean something else?  if so, why would that be matched to `std::string(s)`, which is merely an object `s` of type `std::string`?

Comment: there is some logic to what you're saying though, because I can also do `char *a = &(s[0]); print("%s\n", a);` and that compiles fine... so that matches what?

Comment: std::string &&s is a rvalue reference, not address of the address, and std::string& is lvalue reference, You can read 《C++ Primer》 for more.

Comment: why char* is fine, because it has a  char * function overloading (https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/cc840a4abcd6e0c56cc18edb3965961ce81c656f/libraries/eosiolib/print.hpp#L24)，this is all about C++ language, not the EOS

Comment: I'm having to reacquaint myself with this ancient and arcane language.  it has changed at lot in 30 years since I touched it, but thanks :)